# "64-bit kernel" option selected when compiling kernel, but result is still wrong architecture?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Not sure why I am having this issue. When I select "64-bit kernel" in the menuconfig of the kernel, the kernel compiles as "x86" and not "x86_64"? Meaning I get the following output:

```
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#1)
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

That’s fine, 64-bit x86 kernels are built in `arch/x86`. If you examine the contents of `arch` you’ll see that there is no 64-bit-specific x86 directory, only `x86` which is used for all x86 architectures.